# GetAsync hangs in .net Framework 4.7.2 but not in 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, api

The function below calls an API. Until now the i have used it in a website using .net framework 4.6.2. Now i have to use it in a site using .net framework 4.7.2, but now it hangs after calling :                     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl + "lists/" + listID + "/members?filter[email][eq][]=" + email);

What do I miss

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var apiKey = "hiddenkey";
                var apiSecret = "hiddensecret";account
                var apiUrl = "hiddenurl";
                var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("R");
                var hmacsha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiSecret));
                hmacsha256.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(timeStamp.ToString()));
                var hashstring = BitConverter.ToString(hmacsha256.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                var requestSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashstring));
                var authorizationString = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey + ":" + requestSignature));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authorizationString);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Request-Timestamp", timeStamp);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl + "lists/" + listID + "/members?filter[email][eq][]=" + email);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {

                        return null;
                    }

                }



                return null;
            }
```

Comment: please post also the method signature where this code is situated. Did you follow the async await pattern up to the highest level? or did you mix synchronous and asynchronous processing at some point?

Comment: I mix synchronous and asynchronous processing, but that I also do in the 4.6.2 version.

Comment: this results in a deadlock, could you please post the calling hierarchy with all methods, just the signatures that show where it is `async` and where not

Comment: "I mix synchronous and asynchronous processing," - that's never a good idea, and is *well documented* as being able to cause deadlocks, especially if you're doing "sync over async", i.e. accessing `.Result` or `.Wait()`. So: is it possible that `client.GetAsync(...)` uses "sync over async" internally? because yes, that could cause a deadlock. The fact that it behaves differently between frameworks is interesting (and suggests a sync-context difference), but: if you're relying on an undefined behavior, the result is *allowed* to change between versions, or even just on Tuesdays

Comment: so , the fastest and probably easiest solution would be here to pull the async approach throughout the entire calling hierarchy. I would advise to do that

Comment: Thx for your comments. It works when i go async all the way.

Will take a look at my code.